# How to extract token value from response body in a HTML doctype format - JMETER

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I want to extract a dynamic token named and use it in another call. From the GET call, I get this token in a form of response body HTML which contains my desired token(dynamic value)

Response body is

```
<div class="form-group
    required">
    <label class="form-control-label" for="registration-form-phone">
        Phone Number
        <span class="form-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Enter only numeric digits 0-9. We only call if there is an issue with your order.">&#9432;</span>
    </label>
    <input
        type="tel"
        class="form-control"
        id="registration-form-phone"
        maxlength="10"
        pattern="^[0-9]+$"
        data-missing-error="This field is required."
        data-pattern-mismatch="Please enter a valid phone number"
        data-range-error="Must be 9 characters or less."
        aria-describedby="registration-form-phone-error"
        name="dwfrm_profile_customer_phone" required aria-required="true" value="" maxLength="10" pattern="^[0-9]+$" />
    <div class="invalid-feedback" id="registration-form-phone-error"></div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" **name="cgrf_token" value="jZWOYBqFDvEjoCxSP0aQ9mdufZqwwODp8D74MKo_6uDyL-Zic_ORmQ16f8boHv2-U=**"/>

<button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
        Create Account
</button>
```

Requirement:
Need to extract value under the value attribute right after name="cgrf_token" attribute here. What would be the regex for this?

Thanks

Comment: So basically a regex is required which can extract the value from HTML doctype.

Answer (score 1):

For this use JMeter Post Processor XPath2_Extractor
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath2_Extractor

required XPath is probably `//*[@name='cgrf_token']/@value`

BTW your HTML peace is not valid - try to check it with some online HTML validator

Comment: Hi, I tried with the above approach but the prescribed regex did not worked here. Nor I was able to test it using xpath2 testing in my response. CSS extractor did work and retured multiple matching sets so i set Match no = 1 here to get the first. Thank you for your feedback though as it helped me look in another direction.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended option to extract values from HTML is using [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor)

The relevant selector would be `input[name=cgrf_token]` and the [attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp) is `value`

[image]

More information:

- [CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)
- [How to Use the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: CSS extractor did work and returned multiple matching sets so I set Match no = 1 here to get the first. Thanks.